# ¿Cómo validar un XML en Java y Vaadin?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, vaadin

Hola me dejaron desarrollar un botón el cual sea capaz de subir, validar y guardar archivos xml pero la verdad es que no entiendo como puedo hacerlo, ya mi proyecto tiene una libreria llamada facturaelectronica.jar pero la verdad no comprendo muy bien como hacerlo y ya busque en todas partes pero no hay información, tengo este codigo de una clase llamada factura.java pero no se como usarla o done ponerla o como.

```
public class Factura {

    public static final String UTF8_BOM2 = "\uFEFF";
    public static final String UTF8_BOM = new String("\uFEFF".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    public static void validaFacProveedor(String xml) throws Exception {
        String version;
        String uuid = "";
        String estadoSAT;

        TimbreFiscalDigital timbreFiscalDigital = null;
        Pagos pagos;
        //xmlstringbom = removeUTF8BOM(xmlstring.toString());
        xml = removeUTF8BOM(xml);
        xml = removeUTF8BOM2(xml);

        //validar version 4 del cfdi
        version = FactoryCFDI40.versionXml(xml);

        //obtenemos el Comprobante
        Comprobante cfdi = FactoryCFDI40.Comprobante(xml);

        //extraemos los complementos de pagos y timbre fiscal
        for (Object o : cfdi.getComplemento().getAny()) {
            if (o instanceof TimbreFiscalDigital) {
                timbreFiscalDigital = (TimbreFiscalDigital) o;
                uuid = ((TimbreFiscalDigital) o).getUUID();
            }

                if (o instanceof Pagos.Pago) {
                pagos = (Pagos) o;
            }
        }

        if(timbreFiscalDigital != null) {
            //validamos estado de la factura ante el SAT
            ConsultaSatResult acuse = ConsultaSat.ValidarFactura(cfdi.getEmisor().getRfc(),
                    cfdi.getReceptor().getRfc(), cfdi.getTotal(), uuid);

            estadoSAT = acuse.getEstado();

            //validamos datos de la empres

        }else{
            throw new TimbreException("Timbre invalido o no encontrado");
        }

        /*
            emisor
            validar que rfc proveeedor con rfc
            validar que la no. serie y folio sean lo se capturo en almacen o ordenes de servicio..
            receptor se valida rfc, regimen, se valida uso, sevalida nombre, regimen fiscal, cp, total
            debe coincidir con el documetoporpagar
         */

        CFDv40 c = new CFDv40(cfdi, new String[]{});
    }

    public static String removeUTF8BOM(String s) {
        if (s.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {
            s = s.substring(UTF8_BOM.length());
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static String removeUTF8BOM2(String s) {
        if (s.startsWith(UTF8_BOM2)) {
            s = s.substring(1);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Que deseas validar, la estructura del xml o algún valor? aporta mayor información por favor, revisar  [ask]

Comment: Pues deseo validar todo lo que tiene un XML pues son xml del sat

Comment: lo que es el xml